# Parameter add with value gives System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#

I am trying to to show on a grid values from database based on selection on a combobox.

```
OdbcConnection conexiune;
        OdbcCommand comanda;
        DataSet dsDate;
        OdbcDataReader cititor;
        DataTable tblClienti;

        //conexiune
        conexiune = new OdbcConnection();
        //string
        conexiune.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};database=postgres;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;pwd=cpmsur2ms1;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;fakeoidindex=0;showoidcolumn=0;rowversioning=0;showsystemtables=0;fetch=100;unknownsizes=0;maxvarcharsize=255;maxlongvarcharsize=8190;debug=0;commlog=0;usedeclarefetch=0;textaslongvarchar=1;unknownsaslongvarchar=0;boolsaschar=1;parse=0;extrasystableprefixes=dd_;lfconversion=1;updatablecursors=1;trueisminus1=0;bi=0;byteaaslongvarbinary=0;useserversideprepare=1;lowercaseidentifier=0;gssauthusegss=0;xaopt=1";
        // deschide
        conexiune.Open();

        // interogam tabela 
        comanda = new OdbcCommand();
        comanda.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM comanda WHERE idclient =?";
        comanda.Connection = conexiune;

        //parametru
        string pidClient;
        pidClient = cboClienti.SelectedValue.ToString();
        comanda.Parameters.Clear();
        comanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idclient", pidClient);
        Console.WriteLine(pidClient);


        //citeste
        cititor = comanda.ExecuteReader();

        //tabela
        tblClienti = new DataTable("COMAND");
        tblClienti.Load(cititor);
        dsDate = new DataSet();
        dsDate.Tables.Add(tblClienti);

        //grind
        grdComanda.DataSource = dsDate;
        grdComanda.DataMember = "COMAND";
        grdComanda.Refresh();

        conexiune.Close();
```

idclient is integer type in database.
when i do console.writeline (pidClient) it gives me this :System.Data.DataRowView.

Comment: Research [`Object.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you'll find out why you get `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Comment: Use cboClienti.SelectedItem.Value instead